# Connecting to API with python 2.7 and urllib2

Tags: python

How can I connect to an API using python 2.7. I have recently tried to use urllib2.urlopen('pastedUrl with APIkey') and it is not working. When I try this nothing happens. It just freezes.

```
import urllib2
import json

//api key is not real api key
locu_api = '12345'

url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?has_menu=TRUE&locality=Austin&api_key=locu_api'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

*Update 12/20/15
I didn't want to put my API key in there so I made a variable called "locu_api". But here it is this is exactly what I have in my code:

```
import urllib2
import json

locu_api = '6252bab312fd63a8b43f273bbbc5b8ae973d982'

url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?has_menu=TRUE&locality=Austin&api_key=6252bab312fd63a8b43f273bbbc5b8ae973d982'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

Comment: Why would you post an API key here. _Ever_.

Comment: I modified it. That's not really it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is: You are not using your api key anywhere, the url should look like

```
url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?has_menu=TRUE&locality=Austin&api_key={}'.format(locu_api)
```

With your request you should get an `HTTP Error 401` . If your application really freezes, there is a problem with your connection

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see updated code. Are you saying that I need to have curly braces surrounding my API key?

Comment: @a19i23 no he's not. That's the new formatting syntax, as per [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).